# Change asp.net website language using dropdowm list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to learn localization in asp.net. I'm trying to change label text and Button Caption on choosing language from a drop down. I searched for sample codes and use them. But it's not working. Without using dropdown and setting language using 
statement`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");`  works.. I have generated resource files for English&Hindi.

code and screen images are given
[image]

```
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listvalue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    InitializeCulture();
}
 protected override void InitializeCulture()
{

    if (listvalue != null)
    {
        String selectedLanguage = listvalue;
        UICulture = selectedLanguage;
        Culture = selectedLanguage;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(listvalue);

        /*Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);*/
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Change the initialize culture logic to read the culture info from session/cookie or something similar then change the dropdownlist's event handler to write the selected value into the session/cookie then execute a Response.Redirect().

The InitializeCulture executed before the dropdownlist's event handler.